# "non-existent member function specified as friend" -?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to compile CSSTidy with Visual Studio.

The problem is that it throws

> error C2245: non-existent member function 'umap::erase' specified as friend (member function signature does not match any overload)

pointing to the

```
friend void umap<keyT,valT>::erase(const typename umap<keyT,valT>::iterator& it);
```

which is a declaration in *iterator* class declared in *umap* class.

Can anybody tell me where should I digg into to figure out what the problem really is? AFAIK the source compiles in MinGW ...

Comment: Is it even allowed to befriend _member_ functions?

Comment: @sbi: Yes: http://www.csci.csusb.edu/dick/c++std/cd2/access.html#class.friend . Scroll to #4.

Comment: @Billy: Oops, I didn't know that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix, forward declare "class iterator;" at the top of class umap, and move the impl of "class iterator" to the bottom of class umap. The reason, MickySoft VS appears to have a deficiency that causes it not recognize umap::erase declared below the impl of umap::iterator.

```
template <class keyT, class valT>
class umap 
{
    typedef map<keyT,valT> StoreT;
    typedef std::vector<typename StoreT::iterator> FifoT;
private:
    FifoT sortv;
    StoreT content;

public:

    class iterator;

    [...snip...]

  void erase(const typename umap<keyT,valT>::iterator& it)
  {
   content.erase(*it.pos);
   sortv.erase(it.pos);
  }

    [...snip...]

    // Iterator

    class iterator
    {
    [...snip...]
    }};
```

Answer (score 0):

> source compiles in MinGW

Erm.. so?

Is there a `umap` erase member function visible to the compiler when it's compiling the inner class?

Billy3

Comment: yup, it's public one. as I stated before, MinGW compiles it ... that's strange for me.

Comment: Can you post the method that you'd like that to match? Is the declaration located before or after the `friend` declaration? (MinGW is lax about enforcing the function prototype rule)